# How to handle negation in joined probabilities

Tags: probability

I have a DAG that looks like this:

B<-A->C

Now to calculate p(B,C,A) I can use the joined distribution implied by the DAG
$\begin{align}p(B,C,A)=p(B|A)\cdot p(C|A)\cdot p(A)\end{align}$

If I want to calculate p(B,C) it should work as following:
$\begin{align}p(B,C)=p(B,C,A)+p(B,C,\neg A)\end{align}$

But for the latter I do not know wheather I can use the joined distribution implied by the DAG regarding A since I am conditioning on $\neg A$. Since the Definition of markov factorization property refers to the parents and not their absence I am confused about how to calcuöate it. So my question is, if the following formula can be deduced from the dag:

$\begin{align}p(B,C,\neg A)=p(B|\neg A)\cdot p(C|\neg A)\cdot p(\neg A)\end{align}$

Comment: Thinking more about it, would the correct formula be: $p(B,C,\neg A)=p(B|A) \cdot p(C|A) \cdot p(\neg A)$? This way I use the parents as defined in the definition

Comment: A similar definition can be seen here: https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~steffen/teaching/gm11/dag.pdf in slide 14 and an example in slide 15

Comment: You should define your Markov process, or clarify that you are talking about some different kind of probability space.  In any case an example based on three states or events $A,B,C$ shouldn't be hard to specify.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure what you mean, but the topic is about bayesian networks

Comment: "Bayesian networks" was not mentioned in your Question.  A Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) does not induce a Bayesian network absent some assignment of probabilities and that is also missing from your problem setup.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Bayesian network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network) should help you.  It is not a given that *variables* $A,B,C$ appearing in your graph will be *Boolean*, so in general it does not make sense to ask about their logical negations, e.g. $\lnot A$. It is evident that important context is missing from your Question.

Comment: You are wrong. p(-A)=1-p(A), so it doesnt need to be binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's important here is what the arrows in your graph represent. If it's a causality graph, the arrows are meant to demonstrate causality relations. The absence of a path between B and C that does not go through A seems to indicate that the sigma algebras of B and C are conditionally independent given the sigma algebra of A. In particular this means that the conditional independence holds regardless of whether A does or does not occur.

The following is just simply Bayes rule:

$$p(B,C,A)=p(B|A,C)⋅p(C|A)⋅p(A)$$

We then use conditional independence to equate $P(B|A,C)=P(B|A)$ because B and C are conditionally independent given any simple event from the sigma algebra of A, which contains both A and $\lnot A$ as simple events.

We have a similar Bayes rule for the other case:

$$p(B,C,¬A)=p(B|¬A,C)⋅p(C|¬A)⋅p(¬A)$$

And the conditional independence gives us $P(B|\lnot A,C)=P(B|\lnot A)$ because $\lnot A$ is a simple event in $\sigma(A)$.

So you do not use a different property than in the first case and the conditional independence follows straight from the definition of what your diagram means (but you have not defined what graph you have shown us so it's partially just guessing what it means).

Comment: Thanks a lot. We do not use the the syntax you presented. Instead we were introduced to baysian networks as a DAG and with that got explained conditional independence. Hence it was unclear that not A is in the node labeled as A. Thanks

Comment: If you think about it, it wouldn't make sense to ever include a node for $\lnot A$ separately because it would have exactly the same arrows, only the effect would be the exact opposite. It makes more sense to think of the nodes as questions (e.g. does A occur?) instead of as answers (e.g. A occurs). Mathematically we refer to the questions as sigma algebras, the possible responses to the question as events (viz. "I don't know", "The question doesn't make sense", "A occurs" and "A does not occur") and complete answers to the questions ("A occurs" and "A does not occur") as simple events.

Comment: Also, to relate it to the factorization: basically you just cross out the things you condition on (in this case A) and then you check if they still share a common ancestor. In this case, it's very simple: if you cross out A then B and C are disconnected so they are conditionally independent.